# Determine the group of units of a subset of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. Let $R=\bigg\{\begin{bmatrix}u & v\\ 0 & u\end{bmatrix}:u,v\in\mathbb{C}\bigg\}$.

Determine the group of units $R^{\times}$ of $R$.

**My try:** Let $A=\begin{bmatrix}u & v\\ 0 & u\end{bmatrix}$. Then $\det(A)=u^2$. So, for $u\neq 0$ the matrix $A$ is nonsingular and thus invertible.

We have $A^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}u & v\\ 0 & u\end{bmatrix}^{-1}=\frac{1}{u^2}\begin{bmatrix}u & -v\\ 0 & u\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{u} & \frac{-v}{u^2}\\ 0 & \frac{1}{u}\end{bmatrix}$.

The inverse of $A$ must be in $R$. But I do not know how to justify this.

I would appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Comment: It is $\left[\matrix{a & b\cr 0 & a\cr}\right]$ where $a = 1/u$ and $b = -v/u^2$, so it fits the definition of $R$.

Comment: The first line is very confusing: are we going to define $\;R\;$, or it exists before and we define the ring of matrices, or in fact $\;R\;$ is the ring of matrices with elements from the complex field?

Comment: $R$ is a commutative ring of matrices with elements from the complex field. I am sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @RobertIsrael And $1/u$ is in the complex numbers, right?

Comment: @johnny09, $\Bbb C$ is closed under $+,-,\ast,/$, so yes $1/u\in\Bbb C$ whenever $u\in\Bbb C$. The group of units would just be the set of those elements of $R$ which have $u=0$ under the operation of $R$.

Comment: @learner You mean $u \ne 0$.  $1/u \in \mathbb C$ whenever $u \in \mathbb C \backslash \{0\}$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael, ah yes, silly mistake. My bad.